# Geodesic Equation from Coordinate Transformation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, geodesics

Let $\xi^a$ be the usual coordinates and $x^\mu$ the new coordinates, both flat. Now we know that since the metric is flat, 
$$ \frac{d^2\xi^a}{d\tau^2} = 0 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} \left( \frac{\partial  \xi^a}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{x^\mu }{\partial \tau} \right) = 0$$
Now the proof I have skips directly to
$$ \frac{\partial \xi^a}{\partial x^\mu} \left[ \frac{\partial^2 x^\mu}{\partial \tau^2} + \frac{\partial x^\mu }{\partial \xi^b} \frac{\partial^2 \xi^b}{\partial x^\lambda \partial x^\nu} \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial \tau } \frac{\partial x^\lambda}{\partial \tau} \right] = 0 $$
And from by equating the brackets to zero one gets the geodesic equation,
$$ \ddot{x}^\mu + \Gamma^\mu_{\lambda \nu} \dot{x}^\nu\dot{x}^\lambda = 0$$
For all of the above, I am very comfy, but I was not able to cover the skipped line especially since we now have two indices for x and an extra index for $\xi$. So how do I do this?

Comment: In short, if the metric is flat, i.e. $g_{ij}$ are constant functions in the neighborhood of the tangent vectors, then $\Gamma^{k}_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m}g^{km}\lbrace \frac{\partial g_{jm}}{\partial x^{i}} + \frac{\partial g_{im}}{\partial x^{j}} - \frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^{m}}\rbrace=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is often a tricky (but easy) calculation in GR. Let's start with the fact that in your problem, as one can infer, the metric $g_{\mu \nu} (\xi^\alpha)$ is flat, not $g_{\mu \nu} (x^\alpha)$. In fact, the Simson's comment is wrong since the partial derivatives should be w.r.t. $\xi^\alpha$-coordinates.

Since $g_{\mu \nu} (\xi^\alpha)$ is flat then one has
$$
 \frac{d^2\xi^a}{d\tau^2} = 0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} \left( \frac{\partial  \xi^a}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial x^\mu }{\partial \tau} \right)
\,.
$$
We can now calculate the right hand side of the above:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} \left( \frac{\partial  \xi^a}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{x^\mu }{\partial \tau} \right)
&=
\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial\tau} \frac{\partial^2 \xi^a}{\partial x^\nu \partial x^\mu}
\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial \tau}
+
\frac{\partial  \xi^a}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial^2 x^\mu }{\partial \tau^2}
\\
&=
\frac{\partial  \xi^a}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial^2 x^\mu }{\partial \tau^2}
+
\delta^a_b
\frac{\partial^2 \xi^b}{\partial x^\lambda \partial x^\nu} \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial \tau } \frac{\partial x^\lambda}{\partial \tau}
\,.
\end{align}
$$
Using the fact that $\delta^a_b = \frac{\partial  \xi^a}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial  x^\mu}{\partial \xi^b}$ and factoring out $\frac{\partial  \xi^a}{\partial x^\mu}$ we arrive at:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} \left( \frac{\partial  \xi^a}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{x^\mu }{\partial \tau} \right)
=
\frac{\partial \xi^a}{\partial x^\mu} \left[ \frac{\partial^2 x^\mu}{\partial \tau^2} + \frac{\partial x^\mu }{\partial \xi^b} \frac{\partial^2 \xi^b}{\partial x^\lambda \partial x^\nu} \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial \tau } \frac{\partial x^\lambda}{\partial \tau} \right] 
=
0
\,.
$$
This in turn means that
$$
\frac{\partial^2 x^\mu}{\partial \tau^2} + \frac{\partial x^\mu }{\partial \xi^b} \frac{\partial^2 \xi^b}{\partial x^\lambda \partial x^\nu} \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial \tau } \frac{\partial x^\lambda}{\partial \tau} 
=0
\,.
$$
Now, from the behavior of the Christoffel symbol under coordinate transformation (see the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols#Transformation_law_under_change_of_variable) for instance) we know that
$$
\frac{\partial x^\mu }{\partial \xi^b} \frac{\partial^2 \xi^b}{\partial x^\lambda \partial x^\nu}
=
\Gamma^\mu_{\lambda \nu}(x^\alpha) \,,
$$
since $\Gamma^\mu_{\lambda \nu}(\xi^\alpha) = 0$, as mentioned earlier. Now you have the geodesic equation.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why in your second line you had two indices of x and not just one. Why create mu and nu of x?

Comment: Chain rule! To differentiate $\xi^a$, we differentiate it first w.r.t. to $x^\nu$ and then $x^\nu$ w.r.t. the affine parameter.